# How to add Pulsator4Droid to gradle? Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to add Pulsator4Droid library to my project. It's first library which i want to add, and I don't know where to put the library's code. Here is my app.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.justfashion"
        minSdkVersion 15
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("najnowszy.jks")
            storePassword "asiunia"
            keyAlias "production"
            keyPassword "asiunia"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            //minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            //multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


dependencies {

    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/NativeXMonetizationSDK_v5.4.12.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.3.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/SuperRewards-3.1b.jar')
    compile files('libs/TrialpayAndroidSdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/adcolony.jar')
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile files('libs/adscendmedia1.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile 'com.github.leonardoxh:custom-font:1.2'


    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mediationsdk-6.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/personasdk1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/tapjoyconnectlibrary.jar')
    compile files('libs/vungle-publisher-adaptive-id-3.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/chartboost.jar')
    compile files('libs/applovin-sdk-6.1.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/heyzap.jar')
    compile files('libs/revmob.jar')
    compile project(':appGradeLib')
    //compile project(':sensiblefacebooksdk')
    compile project(':googleplayserviceslib')
    compile files('libs/AdxmiCustomizedSdk_v1.2.0_2015-11-13.jar')
    compile files('libs/AdxmiSdk_v5.4.0_2015-11-12.jar')
    compile project(':unity-ads')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.vstechlab.easyfonts:easyfonts:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.febaisi:custom-textview:0.0.3'
    compile 'com.scopely:fontain:1.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'

}
```

Where to put this code?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>pl.bclogic</groupId>
  <artifactId>pulsator4droid</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Please guys help me, I'm beginner, I want to add this animator library to my project. Thank You a lot! You will save my life! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>pl.bclogic</groupId>
  <artifactId>pulsator4droid</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Above dependency is for maven. Instead you need to add gradle dependency:

```
compile 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
```

in gradle dependency block.

Answer (score 2):

In your app gradle inside dependencies {} you should add following line

```
compile 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
```

That is also explained in [documentation](https://github.com/booncol/Pulsator4Droid) for this library.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `implementation 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3` inside `build.gradle (Module:app)` under `dependencies {}`

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
}
```